# Formulario de registro ejecuta validación antes de llenar campos

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Mi problema es el siguiente, como ven en la imagen estoy generando un formulario de registro pero al abrirlo se ejecuta primero el archivo que envia los datos a la BD y me genera el error de nombres vacíos, les dejo el codigo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['ndn']== 1) {
    $ndn = 1;
}
// login via post data (if user just submitted a login form)
elseif ($_SESSION['ndn']== 2) {
    $ndn = 2 ;
}
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.7', '<')) {
    exit("Sorry, Simple PHP Login does not run on a PHP version smaller than 5.3.7 !");
} else if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0', '<')) {
    // if you are using PHP 5.3 or PHP 5.4 you have to include the password_api_compatibility_library.php
    // (this library adds the PHP 5.5 password hashing functions to older versions of PHP)
    require_once("libraries/password_compatibility_library.php");
}       
        if (empty($_POST['firstname'])){
            $errors[] = "Nombres vacíos";
        } elseif (empty($_POST['lastname'])){
            $errors[] = "Apellidos vacíos";
        }  elseif (empty($_POST['user_name'])) {
            $errors[] = "Nombre de usuario vacío";
        } elseif (empty($_POST['user_password_new']) || empty($_POST['user_password_repeat'])) {
            $errors[] = "Contraseña vacía";
        } elseif ($_POST['user_password_new'] !== $_POST['user_password_repeat']) {
            $errors[] = "la contraseña y la repetición de la contraseña no son lo mismo";
        } elseif (strlen($_POST['user_password_new']) < 6) {
            $errors[] = "La contraseña debe tener como mínimo 6 caracteres";
        } elseif (strlen($_POST['user_name']) > 64 || strlen($_POST['user_name']) < 2) {
            $errors[] = "Nombre de usuario no puede ser inferior a 2 o más de 64 caracteres";
        } elseif (!preg_match('/^[a-z\d]{2,64}$/i', $_POST['user_name'])) {
            $errors[] = "Nombre de usuario no encaja en el esquema de nombre: Sólo aZ y los números están permitidos , de 2 a 64 caracteres";
        } elseif (empty($_POST['user_email'])) {
            $errors[] = "El correo electrónico no puede estar vacío";
        } elseif (strlen($_POST['user_email']) > 64) {
            $errors[] = "El correo electrónico no puede ser superior a 64 caracteres";
        } elseif (!filter_var($_POST['user_email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errors[] = "Su dirección de correo electrónico no está en un formato de correo electrónico válida";
        } elseif (
            !empty($_POST['user_name'])
            && !empty($_POST['firstname'])
            && !empty($_POST['lastname'])
            && strlen($_POST['user_name']) <= 64
            && strlen($_POST['user_name']) >= 2
            && preg_match('/^[a-z\d]{2,64}$/i', $_POST['user_name'])
            && !empty($_POST['user_email'])
            && strlen($_POST['user_email']) <= 64
            && filter_var($_POST['user_email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
            && !empty($_POST['user_password_new'])
            && !empty($_POST['user_password_repeat'])
            && ($_POST['user_password_new'] === $_POST['user_password_repeat'])
        ) {
            require_once ("config/db.php");//Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
            require_once ("config/conexion.php");//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos
            
                // escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code
                
                $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["firstname"],ENT_QUOTES)));
                $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["lastname"],ENT_QUOTES)));
                $user_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["user_name"],ENT_QUOTES)));
                $user_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["user_email"],ENT_QUOTES)));
                $user_password = $_POST['user_password_new'];
                $date_added=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                // crypt the user's password with PHP 5.5's password_hash() function, results in a 60 character
                // hash string. the PASSWORD_DEFAULT constant is defined by the PHP 5.5, or if you are using
                // PHP 5.3/5.4, by the password hashing compatibility library
                $user_password_hash = password_hash($user_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                    
                // check if user or email address already exists
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '" . $user_name . "' OR user_email = '" . $user_email . "';";
                $query_check_user_name = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                $query_check_user=mysqli_num_rows($query_check_user_name);
                if ($query_check_user == 1) {
                    $errors[] = "Lo sentimos , el nombre de usuario ó la dirección de correo electrónico ya está en uso.";
                } else {
                    // write new user's data into database
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, user_name, user_password_hash, user_email, date_added, cedula,nivel)
                            VALUES('".$firstname."','".$lastname."','" . $user_name . "', '" . $user_password_hash . "', '" . $user_email . "','".$date_added."','" . $_SESSION['cedula'] . "','".$ndn."');";
                    $query_new_user_insert = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

                    // if user has been added successfully
                    if ($query_new_user_insert ) {
                        header("location: inicio.php");
                        $messages[] = "La cuenta ha sido creada con éxito.";


                    } else {
                        $errors[] = "Lo sentimos , el registro falló. Por favor, regrese y vuelva a intentarlo.";
                    }
                }
            
        } else {
            $errors[] = "Un error desconocido ocurrió.";
        }
        
        if (isset($errors)){
            
            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                    <strong>Error!</strong> 
                    <?php
                        foreach ($errors as $error) {
                                echo $error;
                            }
                        ?>
            </div>
            <?php
            }
            if (isset($messages)){
                
                ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                        <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
                        <?php
                            foreach ($messages as $message) {
                                    echo $message;
                                }
                            ?>
                </div>
                <?php
            }

?>
```

yo estoy cargando los archivos de la siguiente manera

```
<?php
    /* Connect To Database*/

    require_once ("config/db.php");//Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
    require_once ("config/conexion.php");//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos
    
    $active_usuarios="active";  
    $title="Usuarios | sisegra";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Sistema de Seguimiento a Graduados</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
 
    <link href="css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php
  include("navbar.php");
  ?>  

<?php
    include("ajax/nuevo_usuario.php");
    include("modal/registro_usuarios.php");
    include("modal/editar_usuarios.php");
    include("modal/cambiar_password.php");
    
    ?>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="usuarios.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
<script>
$( "#guardar_usuario" ).submit(function( event ) {
  $('#guardar_datos').attr("disabled", true);

 var parametros = $(this).serialize();
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/nuevo_usuario.php",
            data: parametros,
             beforeSend: function(objeto){
                $("#resultados_ajax").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
              },
            success: function(datos){
            $("#resultados_ajax").html(datos);
            $('#guardar_datos').attr("disabled", false);
            load(1);
          }
    });
  event.preventDefault();
})

$( "#editar_usuario" ).submit(function( event ) {
  $('#actualizar_datos2').attr("disabled", true);
  
 var parametros = $(this).serialize();
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/editar_usuario.php",
            data: parametros,
             beforeSend: function(objeto){
                $("#resultados_ajax2").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
              },
            success: function(datos){
            $("#resultados_ajax2").html(datos);
            $('#actualizar_datos2').attr("disabled", false);
            load(1);
          }
    });
  event.preventDefault();
})

$( "#editar_password" ).submit(function( event ) {
  $('#actualizar_datos3').attr("disabled", true);
  
 var parametros = $(this).serialize();
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/editar_password.php",
            data: parametros,
             beforeSend: function(objeto){
                $("#resultados_ajax3").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
              },
            success: function(datos){
            $("#resultados_ajax3").html(datos);
            $('#actualizar_datos3').attr("disabled", false);
            load(1);
          }
    });
  event.preventDefault();
})
    function get_user_id(id){
        $("#user_id_mod").val(id);
    }

    function obtener_datos(id){
            var cedula = $("#cedula"+id).val();
            var nombres = $("#nombres"+id).val();
            var apellidos = $("#apellidos"+id).val();
            var usuario = $("#usuario"+id).val();
            var email = $("#email"+id).val();

            $("#cedula2").val(cedula);
            $("#mod_id").val(id);
            $("#firstname2").val(nombres);
            $("#lastname2").val(apellidos);
            $("#user_name2").val(usuario);
            $("#user_email2").val(email);
            
        }
</script>
```

y bueno aqui les dejo el registro html

```
<?php
        if (isset($con))
        {
    ?>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i> Agregar nuevo usuario</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="guardar_usuario" name="guardar_usuario">
            <div id="resultados_ajax"></div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Nombres</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Nombres" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lastname" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Apellidos</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Apellidos" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="user_name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Usuario</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_name" name="user_name" placeholder="Usuario" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,64}" title="Nombre de usuario ( sólo letras y números, 2-64 caracteres)"required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="user_email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="user_email" name="user_email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="user_password_new" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Contraseña</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="user_password_new" name="user_password_new" placeholder="Contraseña" pattern=".{6,}" title="Contraseña ( min . 6 caracteres)" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="user_password_repeat" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Repite contraseña</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="user_password_repeat" name="user_password_repeat" placeholder="Repite contraseña" pattern=".{6,}" required>
                </div>
              </div>
             
              

             
             
            
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="guardar_datos">Guardar datos</button>
          </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

en fin amigos, lo que no he podido hacer es que se vea el formulario sin que se ejecute primero el `ajax/nuevo_usuario` ya que si lo hago ya no me inserta en la base de datos.

Lo he intentado de varias formas pero ya no se cómo hacer la verdad.

Comment: Donde esta apuntando tu form ?? No veo su action.

Comment: @Excorpion está serializando el formulario, entonces por defecto el formulario debe estar enviándose a sí mismo

Comment: Deberías verificar que el método es `POST` para evitar mostrar errores en la primera carga: `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { /* Aquí validación y envío en caso de que no haya errores */ }`

Comment: Si, como dice @Triby, es probable que esté usando el mismo PHP para el GET y el POST... la validación la debería hacer solo si el llamado es POST

Comment: Me tomé la libertad de modificar tu título, por favor escribe un título que resuma el problema específico. Revisa [ask] para mejorar tus entradas a futuro.

Comment: muchas gracias a todos , si me funciono como dijo @Triby